# Rotation of (flipping) an advert on Windows Phone, using XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, rotation, ads

I've spent a while trying to flip an ad in WP7 but just can't work out how.
I've got it displaying in portrait, but I would like the advert to display in landscape - whilst the phone is still in portrait mode.

I'm using XNA and Windows Phone 7.1.

How can I do this?

By the way: I used the method outlined in [this tutorial](http://www.expansionflow.com/?p=133) to add the ad.

Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?? I've added a bounty for ideas that work. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you take a different approach. Instead of flipping the ad, flip your game. If you run your game as if it's in landscape when it's in portrait and vice versa then you'll achieve the same effect and it will be completely under your control.

Comment: Yep - have thought of this, not sure it's particularly practical in my situation... unfortunately.

Comment: I've found this answer http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/forums/p/70408/103659.aspx which makes it seem like what you want to do is just not possible without doing code workarounds like the one I mentioned above.

Comment: Great bit of digging; if not exactly what I wanted to hear. If you post it as an answer I can give you the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this answer http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/forums/p/70408/103659.aspx  which makes it seem like what you want to do is just not possible without doing code workarounds like running your game in landscape and rendering it as portrait (and vice versa).

Answer (score -1):

you have to define your SupportedOrientations in the XNA Class constructor.

this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape;

Comment: I'm sure SupportedOrientations gives you the ability to flip the entire screen, not individual components.